# d3 scale: looking for the correct scale, input, range

Tags: d3.js, scale

Fairly new to d3.js, I need to colorize my choropleth map depending on 5 classes of colors.
Supposing my data input are distribute through the values of 0-100, if I use this code:

```
urban_colore = d3.scale.quantize().domain([0, 100]).range(colorbrewer.Oranges[5])
```

it works fine, but, I obtain a coloring based on 5 classes equally distributed in that range: 0-20, 20-40, 40-60,
60-80, 80-100.
The matter is that I need to represent my data based in a different, not equal distribute, color classes: from 0 to 20, from 21 to 50, from 51 to 80, over 80.
I'm really trying to understand wich scale, domain and range I have to set up, but I can't find the way to.
Can anyone help me with the right line of code (and some explanation)?

Comment: You're looking for a threshold scale: [this answer describes the differences](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21789484/3128209) and [this one goes over threshold scales in more detail](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22511734/3128209).  You'll also want to check out the [description of threshold scales in the d3 API](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales).

Comment: @AmeliaBR good memories...and I put a little [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dNH9b/1/) for this.

Comment: Many thanks Amelia for the very quick answer!
I wrote this:

    'var  urban_colore = d3.scale.threshold().domain([20,50,80,100]).range(colorbrewer.Oranges[5]);'

but the console give me an error:
_Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'threshold'_ 
I will check your example soon.

Answer (score 0):

I am not so sure it's me the one who has to answer my own question. But well, thanks to AmeliaBR and  FernOfTheAndes, reading the very good and clear stuff they wrote, I got the solution. Sometimes the d3 Api are a bit esoteric in some statements, and the new adept could get confused. But going to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21789484/3128209) you'll find the differences from a quantize scale and the threshold ones, and in [this one](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#threshold-scales) the threshold scales are explained very well, leaving no more dilemmas about.
This [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dNH9b/1/) is the icing on the cake.
So at the end, even if it's not my cup of the, this code works good for me:

```
`var urban_colore = d3.scale.threshold().domain([20,50,80,100]).range(colorbrewer.Oranges[5]);`
```

(but you must have at least the d3 version 3.0 if not you get a *"Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'threshold'error!"* as it arrived to me)